# Problema con el RadioButton agregado dinámicamente

Tags: html, jsp

He creado un formulario con preguntas, cada pregunta tiene sus respuestas y cada una de ellas tiene su radiobutton, el problema es que tienen que tener **todas el mismo nombre para poder recogerlo en JSP**. name='radio_subpregunta[]'

**Pero** si tienen el mismo nombre es compartido por cualquier tipo de pregunta y obviamente eso no me vale.

Tengo 2 preguntas:
Cosas.
Equipo.

Cada pregunta tiene que tener un radioButton independiente de la otra pregunta.El problema es que si le cambio el "name" de los radioButton, luego no podré recogerlos en el JSP

JSP:

```
request.getParameterValues("radio_subpregunta[]");
```

Si a cada pregunta le pongo un name diferente para que cada una tenga su propio radioButton, luego en el JSP no podría recogerlos porque no sabría que name tendrían.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se puede ver como está marcado "ratón" pero puede irse a " anillo, espada .... " Y NO quiero eso porque es una pregunta diferente.

El código es :

```
    for (var i = 0; i < valor; i++) {
            input += "<div class='col-sm-6'>";
            input += "<label for='pregunta'>Escribe la pregunta: </label><br><input type='text' name='pregunta[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Pon la pregunta: " + i + "' value='' required><br>";
            input += "<label for='pregunta'>Escribe las posibles opciones y después marca la correcta: </label><br>";
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                input += "<label for='subpregunta_" + j + "'>Opción " + j + ":</label>&nbsp&nbsp
                <input type='text' value='' placeholder='Posible opción " + j + "' required name='subpregunta[]'>&nbsp&nbsp
                <input type='radio' name='radio_subpregunta[]' value='subpregunta_"+ i +"_" + j + "' >
                <br>";
            }
            input += "<hr>";
            input += "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: Hola Edu, no está claro lo que preguntas, puedes [edit] para explicar mejor tu problema? Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: He especificado un poco más , espero ser claro ahora.

Comment: Si, pero te falta la pregunta. Estas explicando el problema. Intenta resumir tu duda en una frase interrogativa xD Si no, la gente podria responder a lo que entienden que es tu duda y no acertar exactamente con lo que necesitas. Un saludo

Comment: Hola de nuevo, el problema sería el usar `name='radio_subpregunta[]'`? Podría reemplazarse por `name='radio_pregunta[i]'`.

Comment: Si pongo la [i] cada name tendrá diferente nombre y por tanto se podrán marcar todos los radioButton

Comment: Eso sería si fuese `j`, el valor de `i` solo cambia cada cuatro subpreguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el problema es que solo se pueda seleccionar 1 de cada grupo de 4 y no 1 de la totalidad como te ocurre actualmente. Para poder agruparlos y que, efectivamente, se seleccione 1 por grupo, se tienen que agrupar estos en un bloque `<form>` o usar el atributo `name` como categoría.

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="rojo">Rojo.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="verde">Verde.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="azul">Azul.<br>
</form><br>
<!-- Mismo name, distinto form -->
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="cyan">Cyan.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="magenta">Magenta.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="amarillo">Amarillo.<br>
</form><br>
<!-- Mismo form, distinto name -->
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="rojo">Rojo.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="verde">Verde.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="colores" value="azul">Azul.<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="complementarios" value="cyan">Cyan.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="complementarios" value="magenta">Magenta.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="complementarios" value="amarillo">Amarillo.<br>
</form>
```

Espero que se te haya aclarado el funcionamiento del Radio Button. Solo tienes que encargarte de añadir esos bloques de ese modo en el script que utilizas.

Comment: No puedo dividir las preguntas por formularios, porque entonces sólo se mandaría al servidor un formulario (1pregunta). Hay que enviar todas las preguntas desde el mismo formulario...

Comment: Entonces prueba la segunda opción, usando `name` como categoría.